# R: filter by column given a particular row value

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

I am attempting to perform an unconventional filter of a dataframe. I am looking to filter the columns of a dataframe that have a particular value in a row

To do this the other way around is quite easy using filter in dplyr but I can't seem to figure it out filtering by column instead of the conventional filtering by row.

I have tried using the dplyr filter command but I suspect the command is not designed to perform this function.

```
filter(data,rowname >5)
```

This gives me an error

```
object 'rowname' not found
```

For example:

```
a<-c(1,0,NA,0,1)
b<-c(0,1,1,1,0)
c<-c(1,0,1,0,1)
d<-c(0,NA,1,NA,2)
df<-data.frame(a,b,c,d)
rownames(df) <- c(1:4,"sum_NA")
#filter/select by column
select(df, sum_NA>0)
```

Desired output:

```
        a  d
1       1  0
2       0 NA
3      NA  1
4       0 NA
sum_NA  1  2
```

If anyone has a workaround or a function designed for this, that would be fantastic.

Comment: Please make a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and indicate what your desired output is.  `filter()` works on rows the analog for columns is `select()`.

Comment: @DaveArmstrong, Thanks! I have updated the question with an example and desired output

Comment: Base R solution: `df[apply(df, 2, anyNA)]`.

Comment: https://www.statisticalpoint.com/remove-columns-with-na-in-r/#:~:text=You%20can%20use%20one%20of%20the%20following%20two,%21any%20%28is.na%28.%29%29%29%20Both%20methods%20produce%20the%20same%20result.

Comment: This is a dupe because we already have questions addressing how to drop columns with NA. You are just asking the opposite of it, which can be achieved by dropping the `!` from the solutions in the dupe-target.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `select(where())` from `dplyr`.  The input to `where()` is a function that returns a single `TRUE` or `FALSE` for each column.  In your case, you want to keep any variable where one of the observations is missing.  You could do that with the following:

```r
library(dplyr)
a<-c(1,0,NA,0,1)
b<-c(0,1,1,1,0)
c<-c(1,0,1,0,1)
d<-c(0,NA,1,NA,2)
df<-data.frame(a,b,c,d)
rownames(df) <- c(1:4,"sum_NA")
select(df, where(function(x)any(is.na(x))))
#>         a  d
#> 1       1  0
#> 2       0 NA
#> 3      NA  1
#> 4       0 NA
#> sum_NA  1  2
```

Here are a few other examples that may be useful.  First, what if you wanted only variables where there are at least two missing values, you could use `function(x)sum(is.na(x)) >= 2`

```r
select(df, where(function(x)sum(is.na(x)) >= 2))
#>         d
#> 1       0
#> 2      NA
#> 3       1
#> 4      NA
#> sum_NA  2
```

If you wanted variables that have no missing values, you could use `function(x)!any(is.na(x))`

```r
select(df, where(function(x)!any(is.na(x))))
#>        b c
#> 1      0 1
#> 2      1 0
#> 3      1 1
#> 4      1 0
#> sum_NA 0 1
```

If you wanted to keep all variables that contained a value greater than 1, you could use `function(x)any(na.omit(x) > 1)`

```r
select(df, where(function(x)any(na.omit(x) > 1)))
#>         d
#> 1       0
#> 2      NA
#> 3       1
#> 4      NA
#> sum_NA  2
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: `df %>% select(where(anyNA))` also works.

Comment: @neilfws indeed, it does, thanks for mentioning it.  The solution where you write a function is more general, though.  I included a few other examples that highlights this approach's versatility.